# Asp.net Reportviewer version 12.0 not working with IE 11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, report-viewer2012

I have following code in my asp.net page

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
</head>

<div>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="52%" SizeToReportContent="True" BackColor="#E6E7E8">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

in code behind, i have following code

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report1.rdlc")

 Dim datasource As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsCustomers.Tables(0))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

This page work fine with Chrome, firefox and in Internet Explorer 8.0 but if i run in IE 11.0

If i start debugging mode of IE 11(using F12) and change the IE version to 8 it works.

Can anyone help how to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work when you switch to compatibility mode in IE?

Comment: @WEI_DBA no, only it works when i select IE version 8